# how to uninstall both unixodbc and freetds?

Tags: uninstall

I'm a newbie of using ubuntu, I have followed some guides how to install both unixodbc and freetds, and after I fail to make it work, I decide to uninstall both of them and start from scratch.

here is the command I follow from the guide:

```
wget <the link to download the file>
tar xvzf <the file>
cd <the file folder>
./configure
sudo make install
```

so how do I uninstall both unixodbc and freetds? I have try

```
sudo make uninstall
```

and

```
sudo make clean
```

it doesn't look like I remove the software, as the freetds.conf still in

```
/usr/local/etc
```

But I notice when I run

```
tsql -C
```

it said

```
tsql is not installed.
```

since I didn't do the apt-get way, so it wasn't in the package list, so how do I find out what software/application I installed in the system?

in near future, if I want to install a software that I use 'wget' to download, how do I install that software?

Thank you very much, sorry for asking lots of questions!

Answer (score 1):

First only to inform you, the command

```
sudo make clean
```

doesn't removes the installed files. It exists only, to clean your source folder.

---

As you said

> But I notice when I run
>
> ```
> tsql -C
> ```
>
> it said
>
> ```
> tsql is not installed.
> ```

and there was no error after starting the command

```
sudo make uninstall
```

then the installed files are removed and you can simply remove the configuration file in `/usr/local/etc` via

```
sudo rm /usr/local/etc/freetds.conf
```

---

An other possibility is, install the tool `checkinstall` via

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Go into the source folder, in your question named as `<the file folder>` and start the build process, because you have started `sudo make clean`:

```
./configure
make
```

After that don't use `sudo make install`. Use

```
sudo checkinstall
```

`checkinstall` creates a `deb` package and installs the package on your system. Remove the package and all installed files after that via

```
sudo dpkg -r package_name
```

The correct command (package_name) is shown after `checkinstall` is finished.

---

Use the `checkinstall`-way if you install software from source. In the *most* cases:

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```